# center an image and place a div below it

Tags: html, css

I have two questions. Essentially, I want to display an image in its original size and place it in the middle of the screen(by middle I mean in the "horizontal" middle not the center of the screen), and then place a div with texts right below this image. This is the code I use:

```
<div class="figure">;
<img src="...">;
</div>';
<div class="text">
text here
</div>
```

This is the css:

```
.figure{
position:absolute;
margin:0 auto;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:10px;
top:30px;
}

.figure img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%；
}
```

I have two questions. The first one is when the image height is theoritcally longer than the screen height, there is no vertical scrollbar, the image just got resized to fit the screen. The second question is how can I place the text below the image without knowing the size of the image? I tried figcaption but it doesn't work.

Comment: your image gets resized to fit the screen because you have the height and width set as 100%. that 100% is not 100% of its original size its 100% of the container  that contains the img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it perfect center, you might need `min-height: 100vh;` and `min-width: 100vw;` then use display flex to center it. Otherwise, you might not center it vertically.

Also, move your text block inside one div with the img.

by default, the img will not resize unless you specify it.

By default `div` has display block so it will take the whole row, with `text-align: center;` it will just center your text.

```css
.figure {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
}

.centered {
  text-align: center;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/950x450">
    <div class="centered">
      text here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

First of all I I assume this does what you have in mind.

**html**

```
<img src="https://static.tumblr.com/07f1e3ffdfdd03631d00e7792ea3fa93/mja6mxp/AUUna8jev/tumblr_static_tumblr_static_88o50pnpc3k04gw0ck888o80o_640.jpg"/>
<div class="text">Isn't that pretty!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  color: #eee;
background-image: url("chrome://global/skin/media/imagedoc-darknoise.png");
}

img {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}

.text {
margin: 0 auto;
display: table;
}
```

Your first question about why the image is resized when it's bigger than the page. I have to point out that in your CSS you set the image to be the 100% the of the possible width and height and by default, the images will be stretched to fit the  element.

To answer your second question, because your "figure" div containing the img position is absolute it ignores the position of other elements. Change position to another type such as "position: relative" and it will position its self with other elements in mind.

I'm not the most confident in html and css skills but I hope my two cents at least helps you press on forward.